How to specify DateTime format for parsing json using Source Generation in NativeAOT C# app?
I have .NET 8 C# app with NativeAOT flag
Here is the JsonSerializerContext:
[JsonSourceGenerationOptions(WriteIndented = true)]
[JsonSerializable(typeof(StateRequest))]
[JsonSerializable(typeof(bool))]
[JsonSerializable(typeof(string))]
[JsonSerializable(typeof(DateTime))]
public partial class StateRequestJsonContext : JsonSerializerContext
{
    
}

Deserialize call:
var stateRequest = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<StateRequest>(mergedContent, StateRequestJsonContext.Default.StateRequest);

I'm asking this question because I get an exception:
System.Text.Json.JsonException: 'The JSON value could not be converted to System.DateTime. Path: $.ClientTime | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 650004.'

The date passed: 05/30/2024 09:17:26.003
Note, it has miliseconds
How is to make possible to deserialize this date?

It is generally accepted that dates and times in JSON use the ISO-8601 format yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss. The date you have is not formatted like this and cannot therefore be automatically deserialized.

@phuzi The question is how to make it possible to deserialize

There's some documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/system-text-json-support#custom-support-for--and-
